# How to set up ssh server for mac with custom ip from github?

Tags: ssh, ip, macintosh

I wanted to make an ssh server on my mac, and noticed that the top results on google was go to "sharing", and enable "remote login". But as a techie I know that a `192.168.1.XXX` address is a private address and want a global one.

So on my mac I want to set up a address as my ip if that is fine, or if i could use github, then use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in enabling the *Remote Login* option under *Sharing*.
You are right in recognising that 192.168.XXX.XXX addresses are reserved for private (Local Area Network) addresses.

So if you wanted to SSH into your Mac from outside your (presumably home) network, you will need to make your router forward port 22 (SSH) from the WAN (the internet) to your mac at 192.168.1.XXX port 22.

To do this, you'll need to look for the *Port Forwarding* settings on your router. You can usually access these by going to http://192.168.1.1 (or whatever the IP address is for your router - [how to find it](https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/Browsing_to_the_Default_Gateway_for_your_Modem)). You may find your default username and password printed on your router at the back given by your ISP.

If you have successfully port forwarded SSH traffic from your router to your private ip address, then you shall be able to SSH into your mac by using the normal method except you now have to use your public ip address. This can be found by googling "what's my ip" or from the terminal:

```
curl ipinfo.io/json
```

Then just:

```
ssh [username]@[public ip address]
```

A few caveats though:

1. You must get a static IP address for your Mac on the LAN so that you can port forward for longer than a few hours (or however long your DHCP client lease time is).
2. You should aim to have a static public IP address for your router from your ISP. This is uncommon as most ISPs give dynamic ones which change after a few hours. You can ask them and usually you'd have to pay extra.
3. Understand the risks that come with having your Mac accessible to the whole internet through SSH. Have at least a 9 character randomised mixed-alphanumeric password or just use SSH keys instead and disable *PasswordAuthentication* in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Lastly, I would recommend that you do some reading on basic networking. You should learn the basics of IP addresses, port numbers, servers, firewalls, routing etc. We still have no idea what you're talking about with using GitHub to run an SSH server. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I noticed that You could use custom ip addresses in github for your website, and was wondering if you could use it in the DNS server for my ip address.
Thanks for telling me about the port forwarding! I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your system has an IP address assigned from your router. In most of the cases, it is local address (not private!), because your local network (LAN) is quite independent on the Internet, where you can find all the public IP address.

The guides are right. First you need to set up your server on your local address and once it is done, you need to set up port forwarding in your router to make your SSH server accessible from the Internet (over public IP). But note that this requires you to have access to your router and have assigned public IP address from your Internet provider (which is also not available always, because there is a limited number of IPv4 addresses).